# Getting Amibiguous use of 'init(_:traits:body:)' error with #Preview in Xcode 15.0.1

Tags: swift, preview

I created a preview using the new #Preview syntax for a View and I'm getting the error `Amibiguous use of 'init(_:traits:body:)'`:

```
#Preview {
    let viewModel = RecordingDetailViewModel(recording: nil, viewContext: PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    TranscribingTransitionView(viewModel: viewModel)
}
```

I've tried a few things to resolve it, like adding `return` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77000297/how-to-use-let-constant-in-xcode-15-preview). Sometimes the error will go away when I build my project (and it always builds and runs on the simulator just fine), but as soon as I unpause the Preview, the error comes back.

I still get the error even when I switch back to the old syntax even though the error is showing up in an expansion of the macro that no longer exists:

```
struct TranscribingTransitionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    let viewModel = RecordingDetailViewModel(recording: nil, viewContext: PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    TranscribingTransitionView(viewModel: viewModel)
  }
}
```

Comment: I've had the same issue - possibly a bug...? The only 'solution' I had was to delete the `Preview` code. Not a great answer to the problem, but it's possible the `Preview` macro compliles differently to the  actual build as it's live. My code worked fine in my app just as yours did.

Comment: Yup I ended up doing the same!